# How to set the alignment of UIAlertController programmatically in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift

I took UIAlertController to display the error message. And its default alignment is at the center of the screen. But I want to set its alignment to any position of any specific view.

```
// Here is the code to create UIAlertController programmatically
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.setValue(self.setFontStyle(text: title, textSize: 16, textStyle: "HelveticaNeue-Medium"), forKey: "attributedTitle")
alert.setValue(self.setFontStyle(text: message, textSize: 12, textStyle: "HelveticaNeue"), forKey: "attributedMessage")
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How to set up custom alignment of UIAlertController dynamic?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.I think you have to make your custom Alert.

Comment: This is not possible without doing anything that will get your app rejected.  If you really want the equivalent then you need to develop a completely custom solution

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth - do you know how I can do custom alert box?

Comment: A more complex topic but the basics would be to create a UIViewController with a transparent background (or slightly transparent) and then put UIViews, etc to design the alert controller you want and its position.  Then to display it you can present it modally with a 'overFullScreen' presentation style so that the screen behind it is still visible.  You then need to setup everything yourself either programmatically or via a storyboard.